# Недопонимание с функцией getsockopt()

Tags: c, сокеты, сетевое-программирование

У меня возникла трудность с функцией `getsockopt()`, а если конкретнее, то запуская пример ниже у меня вылезают разные значения:

```
int main(void){
    int testtcp;
    int val;
    socklen_t len;

    testtcp = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    getsockopt(testtcp, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &val, &len);
    printf("%d %i\n", val, len);
}
```

При запуске данного кода у меня появляются значения либо `0 0`, либо `87380 4`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Две ошибки:

1. Не проверяются значения, возвращаемые функциями `socket()`, `getsockopt()` на наличие ошибок
2. Не инициализируется переменная `len` перед вызовом `getsockopt()`

Comment: Да, len - это же значение-результат, не обратил внимание...